# Swift - Alamofire - upload file from photolibrary

Tags: swift, file, reference, upload, alamofire

I'm trying to implement an upload from my **photo-library** with Alamofire:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
        return
    }

    let documentDirectory: NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first! as NSString

    let imageName = "temp"
    let imagePath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(imageName)

    if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 80) {
        do {
            try data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath), options: .atomic)
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    Alamofire.upload(.POST, "\(self.app_url)/user/upload", multipartFormData: { formData in
        let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: image)
        formData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: filePath, name: "upload")
        formData.appendBodyPart(data: "Alamofire".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name: "test")
    }, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success:
            print("SUCCESS")
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    })

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And it prints:

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(_:to:method:headers:)'
```

Can anybody explain me how to resolve this issue?

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 and Alamofire 4

Here is the Full Implementation of how to upload using Alamofire

1. Add the Following to your ViewController Class:

   `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate`
2. Create A Button:

First Create a button and implement the Following method in it for picker view

```
@IBAction func btnSelectProfileImageClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let ImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    ImagePicker.delegate = self
    ImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    
    self.present(ImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    
}
```

3. Then Implement the following UIPicker Methods:

   ```
   func imagePickerController( _ picker: UIImagePickerController,didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[String : Any] )
   {Imgprofile.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}
   ```
4. Make Another Button Which Passes the data to URL using Alamofire and Give an `@IBAction` outlet to it to it :

Enter Following Data to it

```
 @IBAction func btnUpdateProfileSelected(_ sender: Any) {
    
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.Imgprofile.image!, 1)!, withName: "Prescription", fileName: "Profile_Image.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }, to:" Your URL Here where You want to Upload")
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            print(result)
            
            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print(progress)
            })
            
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                //print response.result
                print(response);
            }
            
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError);
        }
    }
}
```

Thats all

Hope This helps

> For **Full sample code** or any doubts please comment. I will provide you
> the sample code for this. Which Includes the Fetching as well as
> upload data using Alamofire.

Thanks